# Anyone know what type of tree this is?

Tags: trees

This is a small tree with clusters of small white nice smelling flowers. Also has many tiny insects That do bite![image]

Comment: add pictures if you want an answer

Answer (score 2):

Probably Japanese Tree Lilac (*Syringa reticulata*); many references on the WWW, not many with closeup pictures of leaf except perhaps https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/shrubs/lilac/japanese-lilac-information.htm. Spectacular flowering in early summer, quite tall (much taller than regular lilacs), very fragrant. Not a great tree for most of the year, looks very ordinary in form unless carefully pruned, but first class when in flower when all is forgiven.

Comment: Some kind of lilac judging by whats left of the flower stalk